# Can I map existing array to `boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object`?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I would like to share an existing C++ array to other processes for manipulation. I can currently do that by copying it to `boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object` and `boost/interprocess/mapped_region`, i.e,

```
contrib_shm = boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object(boost::interprocess::open_or_create,
                                                            contrib_mem_out.c_str(),
                                                          boost::interprocess::read_write);
contrib_shm.truncate(n * size_of_int);
boost::interprocess::mapped_region contrib_region(contrib_shm, boost::interprocess::read_write);
memcpy(contrib_region.get_address(), my_array_of_size_n, n* size_of_int);
```

I was wondering if I can do this:

```
contrib_shm = boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object(boost::interprocess::open_or_create,
                                                            contrib_mem_out.c_str(),
                                                          boost::interprocess::read_write);
contrib_shm.truncate(n * size_of_int);
boost::interprocess::mapped_region contrib_region(contrib_shm, boost::interprocess::read_write, 0, n * sizeof(int), (void *)my_array_of_size_n);
```

Seems like I can: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html

But when I try I keep getting `library_error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can’t.

With a little fore-thought you can, if you avoid putting the array on the heap (or stack) first. This obviously requires you to map the memory ahead of time.

I believe the memory hint you’re trying to use is just that:  a hint. It will be platform dependent what the effect might be, but one thing is sure not to work: an address that is pointing in an area of the process already mapped (to the heap in this case) cannot be honoured.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a preallocated memory, so I cannot map the memory ahead of time. I was thinking if  it is possible to alias the memory pointer somehow, so that the `contrib_region.get_address()` function defers to `my_array_of_size_n`

Comment: Yeah, I got the question the first time. I provided my answer to it. Maybe there are non-portable ways to achieve your goals, with enough special permissions (like debugger permissions). Technically, you’re just opening an other processes’ address space - which is fraught with security implications, but you might be able to get somewhere. I wouldn’t know why it matters, though. I’ve never been in a situation where “somebody else” allocated memory that I somehow need to share across processes zero-copy. Also, look at POSIX splice call with pipes?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will look into them. As the scope of my project is very limited I am not worried about security implications just yet, it is supposed to be a scientific computation application.  I tried simply moving `m_base` pointer from private to public so that I can directly overwrite it, it does not work of course! Anyways, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I've seen projects successfully use hdf5 (https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hdf5) which has support for c++ and python and has modes that allow mapped files. Of course this still assumes you can change the producer side to use it too